# Querying a database to pull up certain rows based on a variable

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I am trying to get the database to query and only show me one row which is determined by an if statement. I can't however get to that stage without first being able to get it to not take the first result it sees.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT password FROM testtable")
rows = cursor.fetchone()
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

That is the current code. How would I be able to get it to select the second row instead of the first row.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just the second row you want, then call `fetchone` twice.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT password FROM testtable")
row2 = cursor.fetchone() and curse.fetchone()
```

We're taking advantage of the fact that `cursor` is like a pointer that points to the `ResultSet` in memory. Whenever `fetchXX` is called, the pointer advances by the number of rows fetched.

If it's the second row and *onwards*, call `fetchone`, discard the result, and then call `fetchall`.

```
cursor.fetchone()
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    ...
```